# How to run a single XCTest case using gcloud for Firebase TestLab

Tags: ios, firebase, gcloud, xctest, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to run my UI tests using `gcloud for Firebase TestLab.`

In Android TestLab documentation it says you can use `--test-targets` to run the specific test class and optionally add the `#` sign for a specific, single test case. 
Does anyone know if it is possible to run a single test class/test case on iOS side?

This command would run all of my test cases in all classes:

```
gcloud firebase test ios run --test /Users/.../Desktop/Archive.zip\
--device model=iphone8,version=14.7,locale=en,orientation=portrait
```

Comment: As mentioned in the Android Test Lab documentation, --test-targets is used to run the specific test class. Could you confirm if you have tried that on ioS?

Comment: @MousumiRoy Yes I can. Can you provide a link of that stuff? I only found that for Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCTest sharding is not currently supported in Test Lab, but it's on our radar.
You can monitor [#ftl-announcements](https://firebase-community.slack.com/messages/ftl-announcements) to get an update when this feature becomes available.